# Number of parameters of tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a project that aims to predict the next character. The predicted character Y is mapped to a One Hot encoding.

| Data | Shape |
| --- | --- |
| One | (N,L,60) |
| Target Data | (N,60) |

Here is my code:

```
HSIZE = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(HSIZE, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(SEQLEN, nb_chars), unroll=True, use_bias=True))
```

And here is the number of parameters printed by `model.summary()`:

[image: number of parameters]

I choose a hidden size of `h = 128`, and I'm wondering how to compute the number of parameters. I tried to do it by hand but I couldn't find the number printed by `model.summary()`.

I know that there are three matrices **U** (for the input), **W** ( for the hidden state), and **V** (for the output), + the biases, I ended up with:

Dim(U) + Dim(W) + Dim(V) = (128,60) + (128,128) + (60,128) + (bias)60+128+128  = 32060.

Any ideas or did you spot any potential misunderstanding from my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleRNN` layer (same holds for the LSTM and GRU layers, and also using `RNN` along with the respective `Cell` classes) does *not* include an output transformation. You can actually kinda guess it by the fact that the summary lists an output shape of 128 units (the state size). It only computes the state sequence.

The number of parameters is thus simply `128*128 + 60*128 + 128 = 24192` (hidden-to-hidden matrix, input-to-hidden matrix, bias).

Comment: That's pretty interesting ! Do you mean that the SimpleRNN actually behaves as an encoder that encodes the sequence to a hidden vector ? what would then be the difference between an MLP Encoder and RNN ?

Comment: With `return_sequences=False`, yes (it returns the RNN state at the final time step only). You can set it to `True` to get the entire sequence of outputs. Either case is different from an MLP though, since an RNN implements a recurrenct equation over the sequence to compute the states. If this is confusing, I would suggest reviewing the basic RNN equations (e.g. chapter 10 of deeplearningbook.org).